# Synchronous startActivityForResult - Waiting for Activity to Complete

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-activity, android-intent, wait

I have an application where I am launching a new Activity, and need to have the result of the activity before proceeding.

I realize that startActivityForResult is asynchronous / non-blocking, and that I can get the result of the activity in the onActivityResult callback.

So I guess what I'm looking for is the best way to wait for the activity to return...
Something like this perhaps? Or is there a better way?

Activity Launcher Function:

```
public String ActivityLauncher()
{
   //Set up Intent
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
   while (mIsActivityDone == false)
   {
       Thread.Sleep(250);
   }
   //Continue with processing
   String data = "<Data from Activity">
   return data;
}
```

Callback:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
   //Pull out the data
   mIsActivityDone = true;
}
```

The data needs to be returned to a higher level calling function - this is why I need to wait for the result in the ActivityLauncher function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will block your UI thread so other activity will not execute either.
I would use some kind of callback class provided by higher level function, in this kind of situation and call its callback function in `onActivityResult`

Comment: Agreed, just move the "// Continue with processing data" into the `onActivityResult()` method.  If you need to do that several times, that's fine too:  that's why startActivityForResult() takes an `int requestCode` argument, which gets passed back to `onActivityResult()`, so you know which request is returning.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the architecture help.

Answer (score 2):

If you can start these activities from a new thread then Android has a solution for you. You can use Instrumentation. Why do you need a new thread? Because startActivitySync will check if you its being invoked in a main thread. If its main thread then it will throw an exception.

Instrumentation lets you monitor an activity. You can monitor this activity in either blocking or non blocking fashion.

```
IntentFilter intF = new IntentFilter("ACTIVITY.THAT.YOU.WANT.TO.LAUNCH");

Instrumentation instrumentation = new Instrumentation();

Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(intF, null, true);
Intent i = new Intent("ACTIVITY.THAT.YOU.WANT.TO.LAUNCH");
instrumentation.startActivitySync(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm actually done with my Android project, so I can't really test this out currently, but I appreciate it!

Comment: Good suggestion.  Just want to add this will only work if your activities reside within the same process (app).  The API does not work across processes.