# How can I make multiple synchronous Speech recognition call on android?

Tags: android, asynchronous, speech-recognition, synchronous

I want to make some Speech to Text call in sequence, I try

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, getString(R.string.set_names));
    intent.putExtra("index", i);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and catch the result in the function:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final int index = intent.getIntExtra("index", 0);
        ...
```

but I think that `onActivityResult` function is called asynchronous. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily abstract from speech recognition here and focus just on parallel programming. All you want to do is just to start an activity and wait for it's result. This question was asked many times here already and you can find the discussion with search, for example check

[Synchronous startActivityForResult - Waiting for Activity to Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351555/synchronous-startactivityforresult-waiting-for-activity-to-complete)

In short, you should avoid blocking the UI thread in waiting for the activity result. That will just block the UI of your applicaiton and it will be closed. Instead, you should just continue processing inside onActivityResult callback. So your code should look like this:

```
startRecognition() {
    runRecognitionStep(0);
}

runRecognitionStep(int index) {
    intent.putExtra("index", index);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

onActivityResult() {
    int i = intent.getExtra("index");
    processResult();
    if (i < 3)
        runRecognitionStep(i + 1);
}
```

Learn how to do callback-based programming, it's easy.

Comment: True, but doesn't work. I think because you cannot pass other parameter to the intent Recognizer.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH, I always get the default value of getIntent().getIntExtra("index", -1);

Comment: You definitely can do that. You are welcome to share an updated code you are using to get help on this issue.