# bitmap is not able to set image in the imageView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-camera-intent

I am new to android app developement I am having problem with "BitMap" and "ImageView"

As always I search stack overflow and various other sources but whatever I am doing I am not able to achieve what I was supposed to and The main problem is with the BitMap.

I tried reducing the size of the image, and also tried loading the static file location, But in case of static file location it worked but when I am trying to do the same thing dynamically I am getting trouble

Although There are no errors but the results are really bad.

```
public String currentPhotoPath;

    public String TruckLoadImageFile = "";

    private File createImageFile() {
        String timeStamp = getCurrentTimeStamp();
        String ImgFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "TRUCK_LOADED";
        File StorageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = null;
        try {
            image = File.createTempFile(ImgFileName, ".jpg", StorageDir);
            currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }

    public void TakeImage() {
        final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photoFile = null;
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

            }
            System.out.print("###################" + photoFile);
            ImageView truckloadImageView = findViewById(R.id.ecoLoadImageView);
            truckloadImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.toString()));

        }
}

        private void DisplayImage () {

            ImageView truckloadImageView = findViewById(R.id.ecoLoadImageView);
            System.out.println("****************" + currentPhotoPath + "***************");
        }

        public void TakeImgButton_Click(View view){
            TakeImage();
            DisplayImage();
    }
}
```

In the log I am getting a message like :

```
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=21KB, data=28KB
       After code cache collection, code=21KB, data=28KB
       Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
```

But If the size was the problem then why it run like a charm with static file.

Comment: You cannot populate the ImageView in TakeImage() method. The jpeg file will be ready after a while, when the system calls onActivityResult() callack in your Activity.

Comment: @Alex Chon So I need to check wether the file is created or not or the file exists at path.

Comment: Yes it would be prudent to check that the image exists. Note that your intent may be taken care of by a 3rd party camera app that could fail to save the picture for any of 100500 legitimate or illegitimate reasons. But first of all, your code *cannot* work correctly, because the picture can not be saved before your app yields control to the system. `startActivityForResult()` will not actually start immediately, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351587/192373.

Comment: @Alex Chon is there an alternate way by which I may be able to achieve the same task with less complexities.

Comment: @Alex Cohn I tried the method described in the official documentation, My app is running but as soon as the camera activity opens my application is crashing.

Comment: The 'official doc' shows the bare minimum of how to capture a picture with a camera. If your app crashes, there is something wrong with it. One typical mistake is to assume that the app will stay in memory while the camera is active. In many cases, the system will shut down your app and restart it after the camera activity is done.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend you to use the lib Picasso, it has large support and also is pretty easy to use. Besides that, you don't have to have this kind of concern.

https://square.github.io/picasso/

```
File f = new File("path-to-file/file.png")
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(f).into(imageView);
```

You can also resize the image, like this:

```
Picasso.get()
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```